# Generate string processing for on rows from some table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've got table with columns and procedure to create SQL table:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQLString =
    '
    '+ ColName + ' ' + ColType + ' '+ ColNullable + ',
    '
FROM FS_Report_Tables WHERE TableId = 0

PRINT ('CREATE TABLE '+ 'Test' + @SQLString)
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE '+ 'Test' + @SQLString)
```

Current code prints only last column when I need all ( without coma at last )

Data table example:

```
ColumnId    TableId ColName ColType ColNullable
1   0   A   int NOT NULL
2   0   B   int NOT NULL
```

How can I build `SQLString` with nodes from `SELECT` from another table?

Comment: Which all are the values from other table? I mean, table name or column name or both?

Comment: @techdo everything about columns : Column1Name Column1DataType Column1Nullable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 
  @SQLString = COALESCE(@SQLString + ', ', '') + ColName + ' ' + ColType + ' ' + ColNullable
from 
  YourTable
select @SQLString

EXEC ('CREATE TABLE YourTableName (' + @SQLString + ')')
```

Comment: It gets only last node from table I need to get all table rows there

Comment: Please add sample data of your table in question. Are the column names saved as rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE '+ @TableName +  
'
( '+@Column1Name+' '+@Column1DataType +' '+@Column1Nullable +') 

'

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLString;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You need to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

SQL server provides you a stored procedure, [**sp_executesql**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which will do this task for you